# Ordering within a json_agg of json objects

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a simple query as follows:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(
                'name','name',
                'score',random(),
                'snippet','random text'
                )) as data
from table;
```

I have simplified the above for the purposes of this question.

This results in something like this being returned:

```
[{"name" : "name", "score" : 0.896277624648064, "snippet" : "random text"},
{"name" : "name", "score" : 0.845714892726392, "snippet" : "random text"},
{"name" : "name", "score" : 0.688958259299397, "snippet" : "random text"},
{"name" : "name", "score" : 0.870620720088482, "snippet" : "random text"},
{"name" : "name", "score" : 0.282366622239351, "snippet" : "random text"}]
```

Is there a way I can order the underlying json_agg by the score within the object?

I've tried:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(
                'name','name',
                'score',random(),
                'snippet','random text'
                ) order by score) as data
from table;
```

And also this:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(
                'name','name',
                'score',random(),
                'snippet','random text'
                ) a order by a->>'score') as data
from table;
```

But both of the above fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how `random()` fits in.  But you can generate the record in the `from` clause and then access the field:

```
select json_agg(jobj order by jobj->>'score')
from table t cross join lateral
     (values (json_build_object('name', 'name',
                                'score', random(),
                                'snippet', 'random text'
                               )
             )
     ) v(jobj);
```

The problem is that Postgres over-optimizes the above and returns the same `score` for all rows.  One solution is to correlate the subquery, forcing evaluation for each row in `t`.  Here is one method that works:

```
select json_agg(jobj order by jobj->>'score')
from t cross join lateral
     (values (json_build_object('name', 'name',
                                'score', (case when t.n is null then random() else random() end),
                                'snippet', 'random text'
                               )
             )
     ) v(jobj);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dc836a7441149c22a35c2a54b996c200) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: perfect, I actually get the score from another column but the query to get it is quite complex so used random for the purpose of the question! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the data isn't coming from pre-existing columns.  You would need to prepare your input so that it is sortable after.

For example:

```
WITH input_data (name, score, snippet) AS
(
  SELECT 'name', random(), 'random text'
  FROM generate_series(1,5) 
)
SELECT json_agg(input_data ORDER BY input_data.score)
FROM input_data;
```